# Proper way of using the time in MSG

Tags: winapi

I'm writing a logging feature that registers socket events. The problem I'm having is that even though I have the `time` of the event in the `MSG` structure that I get when I call `PeekMessage`, the subsequent call to `DispatchMessage` will end up being handled by `WindowProc`, which does not receive the `time` as a parameter.

The "solution" I'm using to log times consists in detecting socket events in the main loop of my Windows application where `PeekMessage` occurs.

Which would be the proper way to do this? I would rather prefer not having to add logging specific logic to an otherwise general routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GetMessageTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644939.aspx) in your socket message handler:

> Retrieves the message time for the last message retrieved by the `GetMessage()` function. The time is a long integer that specifies the elapsed time, in milliseconds, from the time the system was started to the time the message was created (that is, placed in the thread's message queue).

Compared to the `time` field of the [`MSG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958.aspx) structure:

> The time at which the message was posted.

Comment: Thanks Remy. However, I still don't see how this would allow me to move the specific logic outside of the main loop because that would mean to call `GetMessage` in one place and `GetMessageTime` in another (where the specific logic sits). Then there would be no guarantee of the correspondence between the event and its time.

Comment: Your original solution was to call `PeekMessage` in the main loop and get the timestamp from the `MSG` structure. `GetMessageTime` returns the same timestamp. So what is the problem you are having with calling `GetMessageTime` in your `WindowProc` handler?

Comment: It is just that the handler must assume that no other event was read between the time the main loop calls `GetMessage` and the time when the handler calls `GetMessageTime`. However, given that you seem to suggest that this is the proper way to do what I wanted, I will accept your answer. Again, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Between the time `GetMessage` is called and the time the message is dispatched to the handler, there should be no other message processing taking place, unless you have code that pumps the message loop again before `GetMessageTime` is called.